# How to pass subselection of data to child node?

Tags: d3.js

If I have nested array like this

```
var ar = [[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]], [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]]
```

I want to create two svg elements, this is easy

```
var svg = d3.select('div.main`)
  .selectAll('svg')
  .data(ar)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
```

And now I want to bind subarrays to svg selection, something like this

```
var g = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(function(d,i) {return d[i];})
  .enter()
  .append('g')
```

after that the data attached to `g` should be

```
[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]
```

I know what this line is not correct `.data(function(d,i) {return d[i];})` Just do not know how to explain it different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly,

Your are right, the issues arise from the identified line. You don't need to return `d[i]` as the data for the new selection, `d` represents each individual datum associated with each `svg`, `d[i]` represents only a one part of each datum.

If you want each datum, in its entirety, just append a g as normal:

```
var g = svg.append("g");
```

Try `console.log` on `g.data()` and you will see that your data is there still as you want, it is bound to each `g`.

You can then use each of these datums, bound to each `g` and carried over from each `svg`, as data to create new features. Passing the datum looks like: `.data(function(d) { return d; })`. The snippet below should help put it all together:

```js
var data = [[[10,10],[30,30],[50,50]], [[10,20],[80,30],[50,60]] ];

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('svg')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr("height",100)
  .attr("width",200);
  
var g = svg.append("g");

console.log("Data Bound To First G in First SVG:")
console.log(g.data()[0]);
console.log("Data Bound To Second G in Second SVG:")
console.log(g.data()[1]);

// Data is now available to make features:  
g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r",10)
  .attr("cx",function(d) { return d[0] })
  .attr("cy",function(d) { return d[1] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```